# What is the reasoning behind argument that saying I give you divorce 3 times doesn't count as at all?

Tags: talaq

I am not asking for that whether this causes a saying I divorce you three times causes divorce or not. I know there are three opinions.

1. Saying three times at one point does cause complete divorce.
2. ...it counts as only one.
3. ...it doesn't count at all.

The reason I read is that I have forgotten. It was roughly something like the following but it didn't make sense completely.

..Giving three divorces at once is forbidden in Islam and therefore...something... it doesn't count.

Answer (score 2):

Quran explains the right way of giving divorce in detail in [Surah Talaq](http://quran.com/65). The important thing to note that, there is only ONE way to give divorce. If this way is not followed, then it is a upto the authority to handle it. In Prophet Muhammad's (PBUH) time, he was the authority, then the caliphs were the authority. Now, it can be a judge or someone whom everyone agree upon. The thing to note is that Allah did not specified the what should happen when the law is broken. It has been left to us to make any rule that we see fit. One option is that he can render the divorce as invalid. In other case, he can also apply the ruling and make the divorce happen.

Few things to consider BEFORE pronouncing "talaq"

- Before a divorce is pronounced, there should be effort to fix the relation. Elders from both sides should play their part in this.
- It should not be given in a state of anger
- It should not be given during woman's period

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is that if no return (having husband-wife relations) happens no new divorce is possible. New relation is needed to new divorce be counted. Divorce without any prior intimate relation is not a real divorce. So the 3 divorce at one session is counted only one divorce. It is interesting that Islam has a many difficult laws for divorce like witness,... but for marriage Islam laws are very easy. This means that God loves marriage and hates divorce and so made many difficulties for divorce to increase the possibility of return and keeping the family. There is a hadith that says divorce is the most hated home that is built in Islam.

Comment: so this is reason for 2 right..